# Как объединить условие выборки чтобы учесть наличие записей в двух других таблицах?

Tags: sql

Как изменить этот запрос, чтобы число не выбиралось ТОЛЬКО если есть в выборке `b` И в выборке `c`?

```
with a(v) as
(
  select 1 from dual
  union all
  select 2 from dual
  union all
  select 3 from dual
),
b(v) as
(
  select 1 from dual
  union all
  select 9 from dual
  union all
  select 5 from dual
),
c(v) as
(
  select 1 from dual
  union all
  select 2 from dual
  union all
  select 5 from dual
)
select * from a
where 
not exists (select 1 from b where a.v = b.v) and 
not exists(select 1 from c where a.v = c.v);
```

Comment: where not exists (select 1 from b,c where a.v = b.v and a.v = c.v);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where 
not (exists (select 1 from b where a.v = b.v) and 
     exists (select 1 from c where a.v = c.v));
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7479f9276688d116c6223cf52ee785dd)